# How to check if method is declared using reflection?

Tags: java, reflection

I'm thinking about possibility of checking if methods was declared? For example in code

```
class foo
{
 variable.getSomething(true);
}
```

Can I check if method getSomething(true) was declared and what is value of boolean arrgument using reflection?

Comment: Do you mean if the object implements a method? If so is variable supposed to be an instance of the object already defined?

Comment: Yes -> http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/

Comment: Try using getMethod it will throw NoSuchMethodException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the [Class#getMethod()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethod%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class...%29) call for reflection. `method_name` is the method you are looking for. For the primitive you want to just use the lower case `boolean.class`. `Boolean.TYPE` will work as well for the primitive value. `Boolean.class` will not work at all because it is the object type.

```
Class<variable type> clazz = variable.getClass();
try {
    //Boolean.TYPE can be used instead of boolean.class
    Method m = clazz.getMethod("method_name", boolean.class);
    //method exists
 }
 catch(NoSuchMethodException e) {
      //method does not exist
 }
```

Comment: You should provide a little bit of explanation, not only plain code.

Comment: @kocko You were right.  Sometimes I just go for the simple thing first then edit it to contain the full answer.